# PyTorch LSTM States

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch

Consider the following code snipped:

```
lstm = nn.LSTM(10, 5, batch_first=True)
states = (torch.rand(1, 1, 5), torch.rand(1, 1, 5))
h, states = lstm(torch.rand(1, 1, 10), states)
print('h:')
print(h)
print('states[0]:')
print(states[0])
```

**Output:**

```
h:
tensor([[[0.2808, 0.3357, 0.1290, 0.1413, 0.2648]]], grad_fn=<TransposeBackward0>)
states[0]:
tensor([[[0.2808, 0.3357, 0.1290, 0.1413, 0.2648]]], grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
```

---

Because I have to hand over `states` as parameter for the `forward()` anyway I'd prefer using `states[0]` over `h`.

I've just noticed that the `grad_fn` is different, therefore I'm wondering if it makes any difference for backpropagation if using `h` or `states` for further computation of the outputs.

I can hardly imagine that there is a difference, so I'd probably just continue with `states[0]` but I also would like to understand why it is different.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best practice and more intuitive to use `h` or (often called `output`) since `states` are meant to be passed into the lstm for internal use (think of tensorflow's [`dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) to see why this would be the case.

That said you are correct that it actually doesn't make a difference. I'm not sure why the `grad_fn`s are different, but empirically they function the same:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

lstm = nn.LSTM(10, 5, batch_first=True)
state = (torch.rand(1, 1, 5), torch.rand(1, 1, 5))
inp = torch.rand(1, 1, 10)
h, states = lstm(inp, state)

param = next(lstm.parameters())

l1 = h.sum()
l1.backward(retain_graph=True)
g1 = param.grad.clone()

param.grad.zero_()

l2 = states[0].sum()
l2.backward(retain_graph=True)
g2 = param.grad.clone()

print((g1 == g2).all())  # 1
```